# Undefined props in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

This is starting to get really frustrating. Basically, I cannot access `props` in my subcomponents. if I try to render them directly using `this.props`- it works, but if I need to do additional processes with them, or save them into `state`, I get undefined props all the time.  I have a parent component, which looks something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

import Title from './EventSubComponents/Title';
import SessionInfo from './EventSubComponents/SessionInfo';
import SessionTime from './EventSubComponents/SessionTime';
import Location from './EventSubComponents/Location';
import Subscribers from './EventSubComponents/Subscribers';

class EventNode extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'event': [],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getEvent(this.props.location.selectedEventId);
  }

  getEvent(eventId) {
    fetch('/api/v.1.0/event/' + eventId, {mode: 'no-cors'})
      .then(function(response) {
        if(!response.ok) {
          console.log('Failed to get single event.');
          return;
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
          return;
        }
        this.setState({
          'event': data
        })
      });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="event-wrapper">
        <Title 
        title = { this.state.event.title } 
        date = { this.state.event.start }
        />
        <SessionInfo 
          distance = { this.state.event.distance }
          type = { this.state.event.type }
        />
        <SessionTime 
          start = { this.state.event.start }
          end = { this.state.event.end }
        />
        <Location location = { this.state.event.start_location }/>
        <Subscribers 
        subscribers = { this.state.event.subscribers } 
        eventId = { this.state.event._id }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EventNode;
```

And my sub-component `SessionTime`, which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';

class Title extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'title': '',
      'date': '',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.title);
    console.log(this.props.date);
    // undefined both props.
    this.convertToTitleDate(this.props.date);
    this.setState({
      'title': this.props.title
    })
  }

  convertToTitleDate(date) {
    var newDate = moment(date).format('dddd, Do MMMM')
    this.setState({
      'date': newDate,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="event-title-wrapper">
        <h1> { this.state.title } </h1>
        <div className="event-title-date"> { this.state.date } </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Title;
```

Could anyone explain, why both `this.props.date` and `this.props.title` are undefined in my `componentDidMount` function? I have couple more components in my `EventNode` and I have the same problems in them as well.

Changing `componentDidMount` to `componentWillMount` does not help. I am fairly certain I have problems in my parent `EventNode` component, but I cannot figure out where. Inside `EventNode` `render()` all the state variables are defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize `event` to an empty array and pass down `this.state.event.start` and `this.state.event.end` to `SessionTime`, which will both be `undefined` on first render since `event` has not been loaded yet and there are no `start` and `end` properties on the array.

You could instead e.g. set `event` to `null` initially, and return `null` from the render method until the `event` has been loaded.

**Example**

```
class EventNode extends React.Component {
  state = {
    event: null
  };

  // ...

  render() {
    const { event } = this.state;

    if (event === null) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="event-wrapper">
        <Title title={event.title} date={event.start} />
        <SessionInfo distance={event.distance} type={event.type} />
        <SessionTime start={event.start} end={event.end} />
        <Location location={event.start_location} />
        <Subscribers
          subscribers={event.subscribers}
          eventId={this.state.event._id}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```